# How to use string methods on text files?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have to write a program where I need to find

- the number of uppercase letters
- the number of lowercase letters
- the number of digits
- the number of whitespace characters

in a text file and my current code is

```
def lowercase(line_list):

    print("Lower case Letters: ", sum(1 for x in line_list if x.islower))


def uppercase(line_list):

    print("Upper case Letters: ", sum(1 for c in line_list if c.isupper())



def numbers(line_list):

    print("Numbers: ", sum(1 for b in line_list if b.isdigit())


def whitespace(line_list):

    print("Spaces: ", sum(1 for y in line_list if y.isspace())


def main():

    in_file = open("text.txt", "r")

    line = in_file.readline()

    line_list = line.split()

    lowercase(line_list)

    uppercase(line_list)

    numbers(line_list)

    whitespace(line_list)

    in_file.close()


main()
```

However whenever I try to run the script it gives me a syntax error. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please post the error trace

Comment: There's an error in your program: invalid syntax. It highlights the def text

Comment: `islower` is missing a bracket

Comment: you are missing a closing parenthesis at the end of several of your print statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, you have a syntax error in your `lowercase` function (you're missing the parens for the function call `islower`). However, your `main` function also has some problems. Right now, you are only reading in one line of the file. Also, you're splitting that line (`split` splits using space by default, so you will lose the spaces you are trying to count). If you're trying to read the whole thing, not just one line. Try this:

```
def main():
    lower_case = 0
    upper_case = 0
    numbers = 0
    whitespace = 0
    with open("text.txt", "r") as in_file:
        for line in in_file:
            lower_case += sum(1 for x in line if x.islower())
            upper_case += sum(1 for x in line if x.isupper())
            numbers += sum(1 for x in line if x.isdigit())
            whitespace += sum(1 for x in line if x.isspace())

    print 'Lower case Letters: %s' % lower_case
    print 'Upper case Letters: %s' % upper_case
    print 'Numbers: %s' % numbers
    print 'Spaces: %s' % spaces


main()
```

Comment: Ah true, good call @cricket_007, I was thinking in terms of steps - build a list using a list comprehension and then sum that. But you are right - you can skip the whole list step all together.

Comment: It's a generator expression, so no need to build a list. Also, I think you meant `x in line` instead of in test

Comment: And you need `%d` instead of `%s` in your print statements

Comment: Again good call - wasn't proof reading locally. Thanks again! And %s will still work, what's the advantage of using %d since these will definitely be integers?

Answer (score 0):

Here it is code where syntax errors resolved:
You have missed closing parenthesis in several places.

```
def lowercase(line_list):

    print("Lower case Letters: ", sum(1 for x in line_list if x.islower))


def uppercase(line_list):

    print("Upper case Letters: ", sum(1 for c in line_list if c.isupper()))


def numbers(line_list):

    print("Numbers: ", sum(1 for b in line_list if b.isdigit()))


def whitespace(line_list):

    print("Spaces: ", sum(1 for y in line_list if y.isspace()))


def main():

    in_file = open("text.txt", "r")

    line = in_file.readline()

    line_list = line.split()

    lowercase(line_list)

    uppercase(line_list)

    numbers(line_list)

    whitespace(line_list)

    in_file.close()

main()
```

Note: This is only solution for error you faced, there may be any other errors occurring due to the logic issues you have to check for the same.

Comment: It executed succesfully for me, 
`('Lower case Letters: ', 1)
('Upper case Letters: ', 0)
('Numbers: ', 0)
('Spaces: ', 0)
`

Comment: Hmm, I would think you have to actually call the function, otherwise, it always returns true